Calling Thirdparty api to Magento 2 checkout page
We have third party application,we are getting data from that application with the help of API. So here that application will provide one invitation code.Using invitation code will enter to the magento 2 site,that time will get product details once enter the invitation code (1234567).Now consumer adding the products to cart and then they need to do checkout. Here challenge is once consumer proceed to checkout,they want to enter their details,it should be prepopulate. How can we achieve this in Magento 2. Could you please some one guide me.
 Customer should not enter their details.It should be auto populate in this field.

I don't have much code to do this, but I have an idea on how to approach this. It may not be complete, or you may be hitting other issue on the way, but at least this is a place to start.
I am making the  assumption here that the API you are consuming will provide you the customer address.
You can use the event sales_quote_product_add_after that is dispatched every time you add a product to card.
In the observer you will receive the items that are added to the cart, but you care about the quote object which you can get like this
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $items = $observer->getEvent()->getItems();
    if (!isset($items[0])) {
         return; //This should not happen, but let's leave it here
    }
    $quote = $items[0]->getQuote();
    //here you can manipulate the billing and/or shipping address
    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    //...do you magic here and change them id they need changing with the data from your api
}

In the code above, you can check if certain fields of the billing or shipping address are empty and populate them if needed. I suggest not doing this if the addresses are filled in because this event fires ad every add to cart and you may change addresses even when they should not be changed.
